# Guake Window Transparency on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I successfully installed Guake on CentOS using the guide found here:

http://ww.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=threaded&order=ASC&topic_id=33556&forum=56&move=next&topic_time=1317663060

I've added as the last item on my startup applications list to ensure that everything loads including drivers and other daemons before Guake starts. The only problem I'm having is that Guake window can't make its background transparent.

It there anything I can do to fix the transparency problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should go to superuser.com, not StackOverflow.com but I'll answer anyway: Righ click on the open guake window, select preferences, then select the Appearance tab,and at the bottom in Effects there is a slide control which lets you select the transparency level.

Any admin out there can move this question any minute, and some more overzealous user can down voted. By replying I can be down voted :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I already did that before I posted the question. It's not working though.

Comment: Quit Guake, then use some other terminal like xterm and execute guake from there, any missing libraries or other problems should be listed there. Since guake has some python dependencies, there could be unforeseen problems since the package is not native to Centos. Alternatively you can use tilda, which give the same quake like effects and transparency, and has a much reduced memory footprint